# Silverlight Application mapping on local

Tags: c#, xaml, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Sliverlight and using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and have Mapped a Silverlight Application on local containing the client and the server part from TFS (like project and project.web), but after adding all the references with the warning signs , still my solution has a lot of reference errors like resource wrapper doesn't exist, Webcontext is not found, model folder of the web (server) section is not getting detected, and so on and i am unable to build. The web part is successfully building separately though. Please Help!

P.S : I have installed Silverlight 5,RIA Services services V1.0 SP 2,target .Net framework is 4.